# Updating $scope in an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-resource

I m using the following, after much frustration and Googling I cannot get the `data_banks` item to update in the `$scope` after the `$resource` for `Marketplace.buy` has been loaded successfully;

```
myApp.directive('marketplaceBuy', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope', "$timeout", "Marketplace", "Notification", "DataBank", function ($scope, $timeout, Marketplace, Notification, DataBank) {
            $scope.dooo = function(attrs) {
                Marketplace.buy({'item': attrs.itemId},
                    function(){
                        DataBank.query({word: "databanks"}, function(data){
                            $scope.data_bank = data.data;
                        });
                    }, function(resp){
                        Notification.error(resp.data.message);
                    });
            }
        }],
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                $scope.dooo(attrs);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Using `$scope.$apply()` errors.

**EDIT**

The original `data_bank` is loaded like so

```
myControllers.controller('LocationListCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataBank', function($scope, DataBank) {
    $scope.data_bank = DataBank.query({word: "databanks"});
});
```

And it is bound to a view like so

```
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-view>
         <div ng-repeat="blue_print in data_bank.blue_prints">{{ blue_print.name }}</div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Finally the controller is loaded like so using a route

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyInterceptor');

      $routeProvider.
      when('/locations', {
        templateUrl: "/bundles/app/partials/locations.html",
        controller: 'LocationListCtrl'
      })
  }]);
```

Comment: Can't you place the `$scope.doo` function within the link function and avoid the controller option altogether?

Comment: i think he wants to inject Marketplace, DataBank and Notification though and use them

Comment: can you provide us with the view code?  or how does the view have access to this scope?

Comment: Thanks, see my edits for me info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turned out I had gotten ahead of myself and wasn't looking at the whole picture. My directive wasn't actually without my `ng-view`. #lame.

Because I am using Symfony with its own partials I had not realised that my included partial from Symfony was not inside `ng-view` , plus `ng-view` gets replaced anyway by my own Angular templates anyway having the Symfony partial in there wouldn't have worked anyway.

But after all that I am still having issues with a two-way binding and having my directive write back to all instances of an attribute on `$scope` so I have abandoned it in favor of a new approach.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the model.value rule.

```
 $scope.data_bank.data = data.data;
```

In the template, obviously, use {{data_bank.data}}

[Miško Hevery talks about scope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=29m19s)

Comment: this results in `Cannot set property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Pre-create the model in the parent controller. $scope.data_bank = {}

Comment: It's already there in the parent using this same resource call. This should just update it?

Comment: Sorry mate, might be beyond my ng experience

Comment: I have added some more info to the original question, in case you wanted another try?